# How do I pass a variable from a method to a constructor

Tags: java, class

How do I pass a private String variable being assigned as "hi" in one method to a constructor so that when I call the getTemp method in another class I get the result: hi

Class LoginDialog:

```
private String temp;
public void action(){
  String temp = "hi"
}

public LoginDialog() {
    this.temp=temp; 
}

public String getTemp(){
    return this.temp;

}
```

Main:

```
public class main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginDialog n = new LoginDialog();
    String username = n.getTemp();
    System.out.println(username);
}

}
```

Comment: Yuo provide it as an argument to the constructor, and you provide the constructor with a parameter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB`. From what I understand from your question, the objective is to pass the text from the `action()` method in `ClassA` into `ClassB`'s constructor, so that you can access it from `getTemp()` method.

**ClassA.java**

```
public ClassA {
    public ClassA(){
    }

    public String action(){  // notice that the return method is `String`
        return "hi"; 
    }
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```
public ClassB {
    private String temp;
    public classB(String temp){
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getTemp(){
        return this.temp;
    }
}
```

And in your main code you can do this:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
ClassB classB = new ClassB(classA.action());
System.out.println(classB.getTemp());  //result will be 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can do it by this.

```
class LoginDialog {
    private String temp;

    public void action(){
        this.temp="hi";
    }

    public LoginDialog(){
        action();
    }

    public String getTemp(){
        return this.temp;
    }
}

public class main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginDialog n = new LoginDialog();
    String username = n.getTemp();
    System.out.println(username);

    }
}
```